# How to install Vuetify correctly if there is no webpack.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The [Vuetify document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/) says:

> Blockquote
>   Once installed, locate your ***webpack.config.js*** file and copy the snippet below into the rules array. If you have an existing sass rule configured, you may need to apply some or all of the changes below. If you are you looking to utilize the vuetify-loader for treeshaking, ensure that you are on version >=4 of Webpack. You can find more information on setting it up with webpack on the A-la-carte page.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true // optional
          },
          // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            sassOptions: {
              fiber: require('fibers'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

However, there is no `webpack.config.js` in my project. And I did create my project using webpack. 

Could anyone tell me where should I add the specified code into?
Thanks!

Edited:
The reason why I need to add the mentioned code is that I encountered an error:

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:629 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined" found in ---> <VToolbar> <VCard> <StudentInfo> at src/components/StudentInfo.vue <App> at src/App.vue <Root>
```

I googled it and it is said it is because Vuetify is not installed correctly. 

Please take a look at this link, which my problematic file:
https://github.com/powerseed/Test/blob/master/client/src/components/StudentInfo.vue
The `v-toolbar` is the part that causes the error. And if you remove it, the error disappears.

I think if I add the mentioned code into `webpack.congif.js`, it may solve the error, because it is the only part on the Vuetify document that I didn't do. Otherwise I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Doesn't `vue add vuetify` work for you ?

Comment: I dare not to try... If it breaks my project, it is very tedious to remove it. Besides, the vuetify document says if I created my project using webpack, `vue add vuetify` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had difficulty trying to 'vue add vuetify' to my project retrospectively. From now on, when I start a new project I install it from the beginning. If your project is already in dev, you could try doing it via the vue GUI, I've done that in the past for existing projects and had no issues with them breaking.

Comment: I just tried, but it doesn't work. The error still exsit: `webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:629 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined"

found in

---> <VToolbar>
       <VCard>
         <StudentInfo> at src/components/StudentInfo.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>` It is said it is becasue Vuetify is not installed properly.

Comment: Yes, that is the first thing I did, but I didn't add the code mentioned in this post. I guess that is what caused the problem, though I am not sure...

Comment: https://github.com/powerseed/Test/blob/master/client/src/components/StudentInfo.vue Please take a look, this is the problematic file in my project. Sry I have deleted the other code since I am not supposed to share it.

Comment: The <v-toolbar> highlighted by comments is the problematic part. It causes the error I mentioned in previous comment. And if you remove it, the error disappears. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to using vuetify has always been to do the following in your **src/main.js**

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify) //Add any theme modifications here
```

Check out https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/ just below where you found the webpack.config.js

You can set it up using a plugin.js like how it is done in the documentation or how I have above. In my example the webpack.config is not needed!

Comment: This is exact what I did, but I encoutered a bug. Please take a look at the added part of this post. Thanks